# SQL Query logging in extended events deadlock xml report is too short

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, extended-events

How can I tell the sql server to log the whole query in the xml, and not truncate it?

example:

```
   <inputbuf>
(@0 nvarchar(20),@1 nvarchar(10),@2 decimal(38,20),@3 int,@4 datetime,@5 nvarchar(10))IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM "MySQLDB".dbo."MyTable$Reservation Entry" WITH(UPDLOCK)  WHERE ("Item No_"=@0 AND "Location Code"=@1 AND "Quantity (Base)"&gt;@2 AND "Reservation Status"=@3 AND "Expected Receipt Date"&lt;=@4 AND "Variant Code"=@5)) SELECT "timestamp","Entry No_","Positive","Item No_","Location Code","Quantity (Base)","Reservation Status","Description","Creation Date","Transferred from Entry No_","Source Type","Source Subtype","Source ID","Source Batch Name","Source Prod_ Order Line","Source Ref_ No_","Item Ledger Entry No_","Expected Receipt Date","Shipment Date","Serial No_","Created By","Changed By","Qty_ per Unit of Measure","Quantity","Binding","Suppressed Action Msg_","Planning Flexibility","Appl_-to Item Entry","Warranty Date","Expiration Date","Qty_ to Handle (Base)","Qty_ to Invoice (Base)","Quantity Invoiced (Base)","New Serial No_","New Lot No_","Disallow Cancellation","Lot No_","Vari   </inputbuf>
  </process>
```

this is taken from sql server management studio 17.4, management, extended events, sessions, system_health, package0.event_file event detail xml_report value. As you can see the query shown is truncated. Is there a way to tell SQL to log all of the query without truncating it?

If there isn't a way to tell sql not truncate, what is the best way of retrieving the whole query?

Thank you

Comment: By the way, quoting names with `""` is deprecated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If there isn't a way to tell sql not truncate, what is the best way of
> retrieving the whole query

Every `deadlock graph` contains `sqlhandle` for every process that partecipates and it can be used to retrieve `sql_text`:

```
select *
from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(0x01000c001247710230b2bfa34800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

where the value for parameter for `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` is the `sqlhandle` from deadlock graph.

This way you may get your statement if its execution plan is still in `cache`.

You need the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to query `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`.